# .NET MAUI HybridApp Android failure

Tags: android, maui, maui-blazor

My MAUI Blazor application suddenly crashes sometimes with next logs in LogCat, did someone faced the issue before? Unfortunately I don't know how to reproduce this problem but it seems like it happens when I switch pages in Blazor.

````
 Davey! duration=2106ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=1197845, IntendedVsync=30129972966628, Vsync=30129972966628, InputEventId=285688397, HandleInputStart=30129974
 <gsl_ldd_control:553>: ioctl fd 175 code 0xc040094a (IOCTL_KGSL_GPU_COMMAND) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur
 <log_gpu_snapshot:462>: panel.gpuSnapshotPath is not set.not generating user snapshot
 <gsl_ldd_control:553>: ioctl fd 175 code 0xc0200933 (IOCTL_KGSL_TIMESTAMP_EVENT) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
 <ioctl_kgsl_syncobj_create:4451>: (b0, 10, 20950) fail 22 Invalid argument
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglCreateSyncKHR: eglCreateSync failed to create sync object
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglDestroySyncKHR: sync object is not valid.
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to produce a Skia representation from an incompatible backing: EGLImageBacking
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(2930)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glBeginRasterCHROMIUM: passed invalid mailbox.
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(3078)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glRasterCHROMIUM: RasterCHROMIUM without BeginRasterCHROMIUM
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(3163)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glEndRasterCHROMIUM: EndRasterCHROMIUM without BeginRasterCHROMIUM
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to produce a Skia representation from an incompatible backing: EGLImageBacking
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(2930)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glBeginRasterCHROMIUM: passed invalid mailbox.
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(3078)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glRasterCHROMIUM: RasterCHROMIUM without BeginRasterCHROMIUM
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(3163)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glEndRasterCHROMIUM: EndRasterCHROMIUM without BeginRasterCHROMIUM
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to produce a Skia representation from an incompatible backing: EGLImageBacking
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to produce a Skia representation from an incompatible backing: EGLImageBacking
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(2930)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glBeginRasterCHROMIUM: passed invalid mailbox.
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(3078)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glRasterCHROMIUM: RasterCHROMIUM without BeginRasterCHROMIUM
 [ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(3163)] [.RenderWorker-0x20034e900]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glEndRasterCHROMIUM: EndRasterCHROMIUM without BeginRasterCHROMIUM
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to produce a Skia representation from an incompatible backing: EGLImageBacking
 [ERROR:gl_display.cc(515)] EGL Driver message (Critical) : eglCreateImage failed with 0x0000300C
 [ERROR:scoped_egl_image.cc(23)] Failed to create EGLImage: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to produce a Skia representation from an incompatible backing: EGLImageBacking```
````

Comment: It looks like the error on the GPU about the OpenGL

Comment: Agree, however can't understand how did I get it using MAUI, I don't use nothing OpenGL specific, just regular Blazor

Comment: Did you use some methods to create the images or edit the image?

Comment: Actually no, however I use maplibre js library in blazor app, so it may be possible related, thank you for that hint